# Why is my decrypted data formatted like this?

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, crypto++

I am currently working on a side project to learn how to use Crypto++ for encryption/decryption. For testing my project I was given the following values to help setup and validate that my project is working:

```
original string: "100000"
encrypted value: "f3q2PYciHlwmS0S1NFpIdA=="
key and iv: empty byte array
key size: 24 bytes
iv size: 16 bytes
```

The project runs and decrypts the encrypted value okay, but instead of returning

```
"100000"
```

it returns

```
"1 0 0 0 0 0 "
```

where each space is really "\0". Here is my minimal code that I use for decryption:

```
#include "modes.h"
#include "aes.h"
#include "base64.h"

using namespace CryptoPP;

void main()
{
    string strEncoded = "f3q2PYciHlwmS0S1NFpIdA==";
    string strDecrypted;
    string strDecoded;
    byte abKey[24];
    byte abIV[AES::BLOCKSIZE];

    memset(abKey, 0, sizeof(abKey));
    memset(abIV, 0, AES::BLOCKSIZE);

    AES::Decryption cAESDecryption(abKey, sizeof(abKey));
    CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cCBCDecryption(cAESDecryption, abIV);

    StringSource(strEncoded, true, new Base64Decoder(new StringSink(strDecoded)));

    StreamTransformationFilter cDecryptor(cCBCDecryption, new StringSink(strDecrypted));
    cDecryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(strDecoded.c_str()), strDecoded.size());
    cDecryptor.MessageEnd();
}
```

I am okay with using the decrypted value as is, but what I need help understanding is why the decrypted value is showing "1 0 0 0 0 0 " instead of "100000"? By the way, this is built in VS2005 as a Windows Console Application with Crypto++ as a static library and I am using Debug mode to look at the values.

Comment: are your input characters 8 bits or 16 bits?

Comment: @bmm6o I'm not sure how to check that exactly. I have the Character Set set to "Not Set" if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Your code sample isn't complete enough for me to refer to any variable, but the place where "100000" is used, what is it stored in?  What is the type and sizeof for its c_str()?

Comment: @bmm6o I wouldn't be able to tell you since I won't be able to have direct access to the unencrypted value but jww got it right that it was created in C#, so that caused the encrypted string to be a 16-bit binary string.

Comment: Cryptographic algorithms always operate on raw bytes, you are responsible for interpreting those bytes correctly - including using the same character encoding on both ends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `strHex` string, and add the following line after you decrypt the text:

```
StringSource ss2(strDecrypted, true, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(strHex)));
cout << strHex << endl;
```

You should see something similar to:

```
$ ./cryptopp-test.exe
310030003000300030003000
```

As @Maarten said, it looks like UTF-16 LE *without* the BOM. My guess is the sample was created in .Net, and they are asking you to decrypt in C++/Crypto++. I'm guessing .Net because its UTF-16 *and* little endian, while Java is UTF-16 *and* big endian by default (IIRC).

You could also ask that they provide you with strings produced by [`getBytes(Encoding.UTF8)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). That will side step the issue, too.

So the value in `strDecrypted` is *not* a `std::string`. Its just a binary string (a.k.a a [Rope](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Rope.html)) that needs to be converted. For the conversion to UTF-8 (or other narrow character set), I believe you can use [`iconv`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/). `libiconv` is built into GNU Linux's GLIBC (IIRC), and it can be found in the `lib` directory of the BSDs.

If you are on Windows, then use [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: Thanks for hitting the answer on the spot! The encrypted value was created in .Net so that means that the binary string was in 16bits. When I converted it to UTF8 with WideCharToMultiByte it gave me `"100000ì°€ì³Œ"`. I can handle this now.

Comment: You call `WideCharToMultiByte` twice. First time is to determine the size of the buffer; the second time to convert the string. In between the calls, you allocate a buffer. `strDecrypted` is `NULL` terminated, so let the API determine the length of the string. Richter talks about it in his book [Programming Applications for Microsoft Windows](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1572319968).

Comment: I did call the function twice, the size returned 16 on the 1st call, but I will be sure to read that book.

Answer (score 2):

It's very probably just text that is encoded using the [UTF-16LE or UCS-2LE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Examples) [character-encoding](/questions/tagged/character-encoding), apparently without Byte Order Mark (BOM). So to display the text you have to decode it first.

Comment: Replacing `reinterpret_cast<const byte*>` with `reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>` gave me convert parameter errors but when I put `reinterpret_cast<const byte*>` around that I still get the same results.

Comment: Sorry about that, the answer is probably correct, but my C++ string handling is not what it never was. Casting/converting to some kind of array of 16 bit little endian character encoding *should* do the trick, but I'll be darned if I know how.